# Inserting several rows in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I can insert one row in a table using this code:

```
INSERT INTO SCHEME.TABLE
    (col1, col2)
VALUES ('val1', 'val2');
```

I need to insert several rows in a table.

To insert several rows, i've tried:

```
INSERT INTO SCHEME.TABLE
    (col1, col2)
VALUES ('val1', 'val2'),
VALUES ('val1', 'val2');
```

---

```
INSERT INTO SCHEME.TABLE
    (col1, col2)
VALUES ('val1', 'val2'),('val1', 'val2');
```

and some other variations. Niether of them worked :(

Comment: As far as I remember in Oracle you cannot insert multiple literal rows. Just run multiple SQL `INSERT`s. Alternatively, you could use a subquery instead of `VALUES`.

Comment: @TheImpaler Hard to believe:)

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems025.htm

Comment: See the most upvoted (not the accepted) answer from the question I linked above

Comment: The most upvoted answer provides a longer SQL statement than multiple inserts combined. The silver lining is that it executes as a single statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an INSERT statement for each row to insert, like :

```
INSERT INTO SCHEME.TABLE (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2');
INSERT INTO SCHEME.TABLE (col1, col2) VALUES ('val3', 'val4');
```

Or you can use the INSERT ALL construct (but you still need to repeat the table name each time, and you need to finish your statement with some kind of select) :

```
INSERT ALL
    INTO SCHEME.TABLE (col1, col2) VALUES ('val1', 'val2')
    INTO SCHEME.TABLE (col1, col2) VALUES ('val3', 'val4')
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: if i have thousands of rows to insert, and i send them from python process, will multiple INSERT operation be slower than solution from duplicated question?

Comment: Just found out about the « INSERT ALL » statement in Oracle, and updated my answer accordingly